# How do I get the Visual Studio Remotetools onto my Raspberry IoT?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2017, windows-iot-core-10, app-certification-kit

When creating the package for the Microsoft Store, you first have to create the package itself. My problem is step 2. In order to test if the app can go to the store, it has to go through the "Windows App Certification Kit".

For the ARM validation, I can not run the IoT package on my local computer but I have to run it on my IoT device - a Raspberry 3 Windows 10 IoT (10.0.15063.297). I can select it but I get the error message that the connection can not be made. I am supposed to check if the Visual Studio Remote Tools (2015) are installed and configured properly. Odds are that I was able to build and deploy the debug and release version to the device without problems.

I am hoping that you guys can help me out here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)? It says: You cannot validate your app package on a remote ARM device for Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps):

```
You cannot validate your app package on a remote ARM device for Windows 10.
```

So as of now, I think it is impossible to run the Windows App Certification Kit on your Raspberry Pi.